# Why is the Pythagorean Theorem used for error calculation?

Tags: geometry, error-analysis, statistics

They say that if $A = X \times Y$, with $X$ *statistically independent* of $Y$, then

$$\frac{\Delta{A}}{A}=\sqrt{ \left(\frac{\Delta{X}}{X}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{\Delta{Y}}{Y}\right)^2 }$$

I can't understand why that is so geometrically.

If $X$ and $Y$ are interpreted as *lengths* and $A$ as *area*, it is pretty easy to understand, geometrically, that

$$\Delta{A} = X\times\Delta{Y} + Y\times\Delta{X} + \Delta{X}\times\Delta{Y}$$

Ignoring the term $\Delta{X}\times\Delta{Y}$ and dividing the both sides by $A$ ($= X \times Y$), that expression becomes

$$\frac{\Delta{A}}{A} = \frac{\Delta{X}}{X} + \frac{\Delta{Y}}{Y}$$

which is different from

$$\frac{\Delta{A}}{A}=\sqrt{ \left(\frac{\Delta{X}}{X}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{\Delta{Y}}{Y}\right)^2 }$$

which looks like a *distance* calculation. I just can't see how a distance is related to $\Delta{A}$.

Interpreting $A$ as the area of a rectangle in a $XY$ plane, I do see that $\Delta{X}^2+\Delta{Y}^2$ is the how much the distance between two opposite corners of that rectangle varies with changes $\Delta{X}$ in $X$ and $\Delta{Y}$ in $Y$. But $\Delta{A}$ is how much the *area*, not that distance, would vary.

Comment: I think this is better suited for [stats.se]. Your question does not have any physical content.

Comment: @Danu we do these calculations very frequently on physics, it's good to understand them!

Comment: @AndreaDiBiagio I know, but the question has no physics content. It is off-topic for the same reason that a question asking for a proof of the Pythagorean theorem would be off-topic (and better suited for [math.se]).

Comment: I disagree. The _theory of errors_ is about _physical quantities_. I considered posting the question in Mathematics, but I realized that this subject is far more relevant to physicists than to mathematicians.

Comment: Anyway, I could post it in Mathematics _too_ (not sure it's allowed), for the case you decide to close the question here.

Comment: @Danu It is about experimental (or numerical) analysis, I'm inclined to leave it here because those things are on-topic here. Although I don't find it to be a particularly high-level question in those areas so I don't find it all that great of a question. But I think it's at least on-topic.

Comment: @LeonardoCastro Like I said, I think this question would be more at home at [stats.se], not [math.se]. However, if the community consensus is otherwise, I am of course more than willing to accept that!

Comment: @tpg2114 Of course this kind of analysis is *used* in experimental/numerical analysis of physical experiments. However, if you take a look at the actual content of this post there is nothing in it that is specific to physics (as opposed to generic statistical analysis) and hence I feel it belongs on the SE dedicated to (generic) statistical analysis, [stats.se].

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not have any physical content and is therefore better suited for [stats.se].

Comment: I don't think it's off topic. Uncertainty in measurements seems like a part of physics to me. We've taken previous questions of this nature, such as [this one](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/156493/why-do-the-errors-in-a-formula-depend-on-how-its-written).

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/170886/2451

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general formula for error propagation is:

$$\Delta f(x_1,x_2,\ldots)=\sqrt{(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}\Delta x_1)^2  + (\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_2}\Delta x_2)^2 + \cdots}$$
where $\Delta m$ means "standard deviation of lots of repeated measurements of *m*".

Where does this come from? By calculus, when all the $x_i$s vary, it causes the following variation of $f$:
$$\delta f = \sum_i (\partial f / \partial x_i) \delta x_i$$
where $\delta x_i$ is the difference between this particular measurement of $x_i$ and its true value, and $\delta f$ is ditto for $f$. We are assuming that the errors are relatively small (ignore $\delta x_i \delta x_j$ terms etc.)

I think you had all this so far. The part that you're missing is:

**For independent random processes, the variance of the sum is the sum of the variances.**

The analogous statement is *not* true for standard deviations. It is only true for variance, i.e. standard deviation squared.

Since we want the standard deviation of $\delta f$, we need to add up the *variances* of $(\partial f / \partial x_i) \delta x_i$ and then take the square root. So we wind up with the formula that I wrote at the beginning.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get where the **variance of the sum** enters here. The independent random processes are $x_1$, $x_2$, ... , so the "sum" is presumably $x_1+x_2+...$. Or are you referring to the sum of the terms in $\Delta{f} = (\partial f / \partial x_i) \Delta x_i$ ? If so, I don't get what the variance of those terms, or the variance of $\Delta{f}$, would mean. If the variances are the $\Delta$'s squared themselves, so your theorem would rather imply that $(\Delta{f})^2 = (\Delta{x_1})^2 + (\Delta{x_2})^2 + ... $.

Comment: OK. I thought your arguments would only apply if $f = x_1 + x_2 + ...$, but now I understand it from the answer to the other question. The point is that a $\Delta{x}$ is not a _maximum error_. It's a _standard deviation_, with possibility of actual values being out its range, so simple arithmetic does not work.

Comment: I guess you have a summation implicit in $$\Delta f = (\partial f / \partial x_1) \Delta x_1$$. That is $$\Delta f = \sum_i (\partial f / \partial x_i) \Delta x_i$$.

Comment: @LeonardoCastro - Sorry I was speaking loosely and leaving out steps. Thanks for your comments, I just edited, I hope it's better now.

Answer (score 1):

The formula
$$\frac{\Delta{A}}{A} \approx \frac{\Delta{X}}{X} + \frac{\Delta{Y}}{Y} $$

is an approximation because you are ignoring $\Delta X$$\Delta Y$

A better approximation would be

$$\Delta A=\frac{\partial A}{\partial X}\Delta X+\frac{\partial A}{\partial Y}\Delta Y$$

Since *errors always add* we take the absolute magnitude of $\frac{\partial A}{\partial X}$ and $\frac{\partial A}{\partial Y}$, i.e

$$\Delta A=\bigg |\frac{\partial A}{\partial X}\bigg |\Delta X+\bigg |\frac{\partial A}{\partial Y}\bigg |\Delta Y$$

Since it is always tricky do deal with modulus functions, another work around would be squaring individual errors so that they stay positive

$$(\Delta A)^2=\bigg (\frac{\partial A}{\partial X}\bigg)^2(\Delta X)^2+\bigg (\frac{\partial A}{\partial Y}\bigg )^2(\Delta Y)^2$$

$\frac{\partial A}{\partial X}=Y$ and $\frac{\partial A}{\partial Y}=X$

This will give the required form, this is the root mean squared deviation (standard deviation)

Comment: Why do you say *errors always add up*? you could just take the square and then square root to get the rms without having to take absolute values.

Comment: @AndreaDiBiagio errors cannot cancel each other if I'm not wrong, so they always add up, and yes absolute values are not taken even it though seems mathematically right, so we always take the RMS

Comment: The "exact formula"? No, this is a linear approximation used for uncertainties that are normally distributed.

Comment: @RobJeffries The OP has given that X is independent of Y, So why wouldnt this be an exact formuia?

Comment: So, squaring all terms is a workaround, kind of a tricky, for not to deal with _modulus_? The square of the sum isn't the sum of the squares, generally.

Comment: I never said that square of the sum is equal to the sum of squares, I'm _not_ squaring on both sides, the formula for standard deviation $\sigma_x$ is also done in a similar way, look up standard deviation

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Pythagoras, but it is only remotely related.  The important concept, as presented in SteveB's answer, is that the variables are considered to be independent, i.e. one does not affect the other.  In mathematics, independent parameters are said to be **orthogonal** , and can thus be assigned to separate axes in Cartesian N-space.  It just so happens that the root-sum-square error turns out to be the diagonal of the N-cube (or rectangle in 2-D), which matches Pythagoras'  trigonometry theorem.

Answer (score 0):

The square root is there as a better estimator of the error than just adding the errors together.  If you add the errors together you are finding the maximum possible error which will happen when both quantities are a maximum(or minimum) together.  This is an unlikely event compared with all the other domination of errors.  The square root formula you you quote has been deduced by statisticians assume, I think, a normal distribution of random errors.  You might look up "theory of errors" to get a more detail answer to your question.