# Is fractional error computed using the actual value or the best estimate?

Tags: error-analysis

I'm trying to figure out which is the best way to do error propagation for situations when you have a product.

For instance, for $F(x,y) = xy$, we can use Taylor expansion and keeping 1st order terms:

$$
\delta F = \frac{\partial F}{\partial x}(x_0,y_0) \delta x + \frac{\partial F}{\partial y}(x_0,y_0) \delta y
$$

where $\delta F = F(x,y)-F(x_0,y_0)$, $\delta x = x-x_0$, and $\delta y = y-y_0$.

After computing the partial derivatives,

$$
\delta F = y_0 \delta x + x_0 \delta y
$$

Then squaring the above equation and assuming there is no correlation between the error in x and error in y (i.e. $\langle\delta x \delta y\rangle = 0$), $\delta F$ can be redefined to be a definite positive number:

$$
\delta F := \sqrt{(y_0 \delta x)^2 + (x_0 \delta y)^2}
$$

Then one would write quantities which are calculated from measured quantities as:  $F = F_0 \pm \delta F$, where $F_0$ is the best estimate of $F$, and $\delta F$ is the propagated error.

So if we were given $x = 20 \pm 1$ and $y = 40 \pm 3$, then I can say $x_0 = 20$, $\delta x = 1$, $y_0 = 40$, and $\delta y = 3$.  Then $F_0 = x_0 y_0 = 800$ and $\delta F = \sqrt{40^2 + 60^2} = 10\sqrt{52} \approx 70$.  Therefore $F = 800 \pm 70$.  This definition defines a clear procedure.

However, in one of my lab manuals, a different and more confusing approached was used to deal with error propagation in products.  It uses fractional errors and more ambiguous notation:

$$
\delta F = y \delta x + x \delta y
$$

Then dividing by $F=xy$:

$$
\frac{\delta F}{F} = \frac{\delta x}{x} + \frac{\delta y}{y}
$$

Squaring and assuming no correlation in errors of independent variables:

$$
\frac{\delta F}{F} = \sqrt{\biggl(\frac{\delta x}{x}\biggr)^2 + \biggl(\frac{\delta y}{y}\biggr)^2}
$$

The reason this confuses me is that I'd expect fractional error be such that the $\frac{\delta F}{F}$ is the error in F divided by the **actual** value of $F$, and not, for instance, the best estimate, $F_0$.  Thus in dividing by $F = xy$, the values $x$ and $y$ on the right hand side of the equations would also be the **actual** values of their respective quantities.  In experiments, we don't always know the actual values.

But let's say we try to use what we do know.  Given some $x = x_0 \pm \delta x$ and $y = y_0 \pm \delta y$, this version of the propagated error would be very burdensome to calculate.  In fact, to be explicit:

$$
\delta F = F - F_0 = F \sqrt{\biggl(\frac{\delta x}{x_0 \pm \delta x}\biggr)^2 + \biggl(\frac{\delta y}{y_0 \pm \delta y}\biggr)^2}
$$

thus

$$
F = F_0 \left[\sqrt{\biggl(\frac{\delta x}{x_0 \pm \delta x}\biggr)^2 + \biggl(\frac{\delta y}{y_0 \pm \delta y}\biggr)^2}\right]^{-1}
$$

and you would have $(x \pm \delta x)^2$ and $(y \pm \delta y)^2$ terms to deal with. This would lead to having to consider all sorts of cases for different combinations of signs.

Assuming instead that $\frac{\delta F}{F}$ is actually the propagated error divided by the **best estimate** in F, we return to the first result.

Comment: You've defined $F$ as $xy$ so why do you later add $x_0$ and $y_0$? Shouldn't $F_0=x_0y_0=800$? Or at least of that order...

Comment: You're right, x is not necessarily the same as x0 + dx.

Comment: Yes, my mistake.... :(

Comment: Ok but then the error is order $10\%$ Or am I wrong?

Comment: Yes the error is just under 10%, and the error in x and y are likewise are in the order just under 10%, so this looks right to me.

Comment: So would the way to compute F from dF/F = G(x, y, dx, dy) simply to plug in the values F=F0, x=x0, and y=y0, solve for dF, and then use F = F0 +- dF?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/772859/226902, https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/170886/226902, https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/233724/226902,  https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/432871/226902, https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/59628/226902.

Answer (score 2):

You do it this way because you don't *have* the actual value of $F$, so it is impossible to divide by it. In the second part of your question, when you discuss the procedure from your lab manual, $F$ refers to the best estimate, i.e. the measured value. That's what you divide by.

Bear in mind that something like $F \pm \delta F$ (or, if you prefer, $F_0 \pm \delta F$) represents a probability distribution, not a number. Typically, the best estimate $F$ (or $F_0$) is the mean of the distribution, and $\delta F$ is its standard deviation. The numerical value you get by adding $F + \delta F$ (or $F_0 + \delta F$) is fairly meaningless; it's only one of many possible values that the true value of the measurement could be.

Comment: Darn Physics texts and their ambiguous use of Taylor Approximations >:(