# A question about the propagation of uncertainties

Tags: error-analysis, statistics

> If we have $f(x,y)=f(\overline{x}\pm\sigma_x,\overline{y}\pm\sigma_y)$ how is then $$\sigma_f=\sqrt{\left(\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{x}}\right)^2\sigma_x^2+\left(\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{y}}\right)^2\sigma_y^2}~~~?$$

I have looked at [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propagation_of_uncertainty#Non-linear_combinations) Wikipedia page but I don't quite understand this approach since I'm not familiar with approximating functions with Taylor series. I have also found that in [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V0ZRvvHfF0E) video it is said that that way of calculating the standard deviation for multivariate functions somehow gives us a average standard deviation but I don't understand why/how.

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/59628/2451 , http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/170886/2451 , http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/233724/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Taylor series are very very important in all of  science and one major application of derivatives. The concept is not hard to understand and I am sure that there are many good sources to learn the basics. The low order Taylor approximation is essential for uncertanty propagation.

Comment: Thanks, I've seen that there's no way around it, and since I'm sure I'm going to have lectures about it sooner or later,  I'm trying to understand it right now. Also the question I posted does have a complete answer on the first link @Qmechanic provided.